# how to implement a simple Android OAuth and server API

Tags: php, android, authentication, oauth

i have an android app that sends data to my web server (data is processed by php and stored in mysql db).  for security reasons, i need to verify that the user sending the data is who he/she says he/she is.

i do not want to verify login/password, i would rather use the phone's registered (account manager) google account with something like federated login.  i played around with  [nick johnson's example for GAE](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app), but it is specific for GAE based apps and does not permit integration with my own server API's, therefore authentication does not work (i get a google authToken, but it is meaningless for my server API).

from what i understand, the safest+simplest solution would be to use OAuth.

but i am completely stumped trying to understand OAuth (i understand its concepts, but have not been able to find any example that i could implement).

does anyone have anything like a functional example that i could play around with and tweak for my needs?  thanx in advance!

Comment: i actually got a bronze badge (TUMBLEWEED) for this: no answers, no comments and low views for a week!  LOL!!!

Answer (score -1):

when ever a user login or use your app first time , you should capture his/her device mac address, and store it to the database, and you can easily authenticate user using this mac address

Comment: interesting suggestion, but (in this case) i need to identify the user, not the equipment.  user may log in from various devices, change equipment, etc.

Comment: What about instances of MAC spoofing. Also since android marshmallow its now more difficult to read MAC address; it might also entail the user switching on GPS etc. :(